# Spring MVC 3.2 -- NotReadablePropertyException

Tags: spring-mvc, readable

I am getting the following exception in my Spring 3.2 application:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'name' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'name' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:729)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:721)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:164)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:151)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.EnterBulletin_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(EnterBulletin_jsp.java:403)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.EnterBulletin_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(EnterBulletin_jsp.java:347)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.EnterBulletin_jsp._jspService(EnterBulletin_jsp.java:108)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1265)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1016)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:859)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:792)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is the method in my controller.  I'm putting an ArrayList into the command object, so it would appear there's a problem getting the Bulletin objects out of the command object later on.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getApprovedBulletins", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView getApprovedBulletins(
        @ModelAttribute("bulletin") Bulletin bulletin, BindingResult result) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

    try {
        List<Bulletin> bulletins = bulletinDAO.getApprovedBulletins();
        mav.setViewName("EnterBulletin");
        if (bulletins != null) {
            mav.addObject("command", bulletins);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        mav.setViewName("FailurePage");
    }

    return mav;
}
```

For some reason, the problem is being flagged on the  line in the form at the top of the page, when what I'm trying to do is list the bulletins at the top.  Here is the JSP.  Any ideas?

```
<body>
    <h1>Job Connections Bulletin Board</h1>
    <h2>Bulletin Entry</h2>
    <b><font color="red"><c:out value='${confirmation}' /></font></b>
    <c:remove var="confirmation" scope="session" />
    <p>Here you can post comments, announce jobs, etc. All comments are
        subject to approval.</p>
    <p>
        To search bulletins, click <a href="SearchPage.jsp">here</a>.
    </p>
    <c:forEach var="bulletin" items="${bulletins}">
        <c:if test="${bulletin.approved}">
            <c:url value="/getSingleBulletin"
                var="{bulletin.name} -- {bulletin.subject}">
                <c:param name="id">${bulletin.id}</c:param>
            </c:url>
            <br />
            <br />
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
    <form:form command="bulletin" method="post" action="/processBulletin">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><form:input path="name" maxlength="30" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Subject:</td>
                <td><form:input path="subject" maxlength="50" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Message:</td>
                <td><form:textarea path="note" cols="50" rows="50" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" value="Submit bulletin" name="submit" /></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
```

Comment: I looks like you are trying to call the "name" property on an ArrayList, maybe in your JSP?  ArrayList does not have a getName(), at least that I know of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.  I put the List in the session object, then I put an instance of Bulletin in the command object.  My code now looks like this.

```
List<Bulletin> bulletins = bulletinDAO.getApprovedBulletins();
mav.setViewName("EnterBulletin");
if (bulletins != null) {
    ServletRequestAttributes attributes = 
        (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
    HttpSession session = attributes.getRequest().getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("bulletins", bulletins);
    mav.addObject("command", new Bulletin());
}
```